# Unable to Start gcloud instance with more GPUs despite increasing quota

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Relatively new to using gcloud suite and I'm having trouble starting my instance with more GPUs. Initially adding the first GPU was no issue in requesting a quota increase.

However, when I requested another increase to my GPU quota to improve the training time for my model, after getting approval and assigning another GPU to my instance, I am still receiving an error message that my instance cannot be started because it exceeded the allocated quota of 1 despite seeing in the admin console that the quota is 2.

Console:

[image: Console shows 2]

Error:

> Starting instance(s) my-fastai-instance...failed.
>   ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.start) Quota 'PREEMPTIBLE_NVIDIA_T4_GPUS' exceeded.  Limit: 1.0 in region us-west1.

Is there something else I need to change in order to get the extra GPU to work with the instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's a distinction between "NVIDIA T4 GPUs" and "Preemptible NVIDIA T4 GPUs".

You've a quota of 2 for the "NVIDIA T4 GPUs" and -- I assume -- a quota of 1 for the "Preemptible NVIDIA T4 GPUs".

As you did before, you need to request these by region.

**NB** You should be able to proceed immediately by switching your instance from requesting "Preemptible NVIDIA T4 GPUs" to "NVIDIA T4 GPUs"

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I was not aware of this. Is there a straightforward way to change my instance to non-preemptible? I am in the edit panel for my instance and see the preemptible attribute shown, but no option or way to change it which makes me think that it needs to be re-created or cloned?

I will most likely stay as preemptible for cost reasons, but searching through the gcloud docs did not really mention this explicitly either (Only that changing attributes should be done in edit).

Comment: You cannot change the preemptibility of an instance once created. It can feel more burdensome (particularly if you prefer using the Console), but it's good practice to (a) script your cloud provisioning commands; (b) not edit but create resources anew. Many Console pages include "Show equivalent REST or command line" functionality and this can be used to become familiar with the Cloud SDK (aka "gcloud") command-line. The intent is to be able to (re)create e.g. a VM from scratch whenever you wish. Make sense? Hopefully, your quota request for Preemptible GPUs has already been approved.